# override exception handling in class function of imported module

Tags: python, exception, module

I have a definition inside of a class which handles an exception in a manner I don't like.

The class itself is inside a module, which itself is called by a module that I import.

the error handling I don't like looks like this:

```
class BitSharesWebsocket(Events):

    #[snip]

    def run_forever(self):
        """ This method is used to run the websocket app continuously.
            It will execute callbacks as defined and try to stay
            connected with the provided APIs
        """
        cnt = 0
        while not self.run_event.is_set():
            cnt += 1
            self.url = next(self.urls)
            log.debug("Trying to connect to node %s" % self.url)
            try:
                # websocket.enableTrace(True)
                self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
                    self.url,
                    on_message=self.on_message,
                    on_error=self.on_error,
                    on_close=self.on_close,
                    on_open=self.on_open
                )
                self.ws.run_forever()
            except websocket.WebSocketException as exc:
                if (self.num_retries >= 0 and cnt > self.num_retries):
                    raise NumRetriesReached()

                sleeptime = (cnt - 1) * 2 if cnt < 10 else 10
                if sleeptime:
                    log.warning(
                        "Lost connection to node during wsconnect(): %s (%d/%d) "
                        % (self.url, cnt, self.num_retries) +
                        "Retrying in %d seconds" % sleeptime
                    )
                    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

I wish to preempt the exception here:

```
except websocket.WebSocketException as exc:
```

and handle it in my own way, namely to try a new address rather than trying the same address again and again.

I am presented with this exception when calling:

```
from bitshares.blockchain import Blockchain
from bitshares import BitShares

try:
    chain = Blockchain(bitshares_instance=BitShares(n))
except:
    print ('hello world')
    pass
```

when n is a bad/unresponsive websocket address

I never get the 'hello world' message because the module handles the exception before I do.

the module is hosted at github here:

https://github.com/xeroc/python-bitshares/blob/9250544ca8eadf66de31c7f38fc37294c11f9548/bitsharesapi/websocket.py

I can do:

```
from bitsharesapi import websocket as ws
```

but I am not sure what to do with the module ws now that it is imported to preempt its exception handling, or if this is even the correct way to approach it.

Comment: Short answer : there's no way to "preempt" exception handling this way - except of course to fork the whole thing and rewrite it your way. Longer answer: technically, there's probably a way to do it - but then it's gonna be even more complicated and unmaintainable than a fork. Note that  if you fork the project you can try and rewrite it in a way that maintains compatibility, and submit your fork to the project's maintainer.

Comment: I have contacted the dev and suggested he simply raise the exception, letting users handle it in their own way.  I was looking for an "until that happens" solution.  I'm currently using multiprocess to override and enforce timeout; but this has some drawbacks in practice as you allude.  I was hoping for "from bitsharesapi import websocket.WebSocketException" or the like

Comment: What would you do with it then ? An exception is just an object, it's not the control flow. You cannot change the control flow of a part of code without changing that code,  unless of course the given code provide hooks to do so - through callbacks or by using the template method pattern and inheritance - but even then you can only take (partial) control over the parts that delegates to those hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue here:

```
chain = Blockchain(bitshares_instance=BitShares(n))
```

I was able to do:

```
chain = Blockchain(bitshares_instance=BitShares(n,num_retries=0))
```

I had previously tried this and assumed it wouldn't work:

```
chain = Blockchain(bitshares_instance=BitShares(n),num_retries=0)
```

*note parenthesis placement